# Finding the index of the first occurrence of any item in a list

Tags: python, string

For the list shown in the example:

```
my_list = ['hi', 'babe', 'hi', 'babe', 'key', 'key']

output = [0, 1, 4]
```

or

```
output =[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

Comment: What did you try, what does not work? Use a `set()` to get the uniques, use `list.index()` or `list.find()` to get your data ...

Comment: `my_list` does not contain any unique element. Furthermore, it seems you are looking for the index of the first occurrence of any item in a list - I'd suggest rewording the question

Comment: @ack Agreed and done.

Answer (score 4):

Turn the list to a set then use `.index`:

```
output = [my_list.index(elem) for elem in set(my_list)]
```

Since `set` is unordered you may want to sort the output:

```
output = sorted(my_list.index(elem) for elem in set(my_list))
```

Full example:

```
>>> my_list = ['hi', 'babe', 'hi', 'babe', 'key', 'key']         
>>> output = sorted(my_list.index(elem) for elem in set(my_list))
>>> output                                                       
[0, 1, 4]
```

Comment: @tobias_k ... Probably sorting is not needed. So, [4, 0, 1] is fine. As I will need to use the idx to select the items from my_list, and some other data. To do this for my_list, I used:  pandas ...  my_list = pd.Series(my_list); my_list = my_list.get(output); ...not sure if this is the best way to do it? And thanks for your input anyways!

Comment: @innuendo Well, that's a great example of an XY problem. You should have mentioned that your data is in a dataframe. pandas offer vectorized operations that may achieve what you are looking for much faster than any Python loop can achieve

Comment: @DeepSpace  ..As I am a bit new to Python, and still tagged with C++ mentality, I am still not sure if there is a panda function that gives the intended output ..output = [0, 1, 4] or even  [4, 0, 1].

Comment: @innuendo Sorting is not the problem here, but the repeated calls to `index`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `set` to keep track of already-seen elements and use a loop or list comprehension to get whether each element is the first of its kind. Then, use `enumerate` to get the indices.

```
>>> seen = set()
>>> [int(not(s in seen or seen.add(s))) for s in my_list]
[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
>>> [i for i, e in enumerate(_) if e]
[0, 1, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also collect indices in a dictionary, where only the first occurence of each item is recorded:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

my_list = ['hi', 'babe', 'hi', 'babe', 'key', 'key']

d = OrderedDict()
for i, item in enumerate(my_list):
    d.setdefault(item, i)

print([d[k] for k in d])
# [0, 1, 4]
```

A [`collections.OrderedDict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) is used to maintain order of insertion.

Comment: Why the list? How about just `d.setdefault(item, i)`?

Comment: @tobias_k Much smarter, updated my answer. I also realised quickly afterwards that the list is just pointless.

Answer (score 0):

The list has a build in function .index:

```
my_list = ['hi', 'babe', 'hi', 'babe', 'key', 'key']
my_list.index('hi')
>>>0
```

.index searches through the list in order until it finds a match then and stops. If you expect to need indices of more matches, you should use a list comprehension. First, you may want to convert your text into numbers (lists of numbers will not need that) e.g hi = 0, babe = 1 etc. This should do it (might be a better way):

```
unique_words_list = []
number_list = []
for word in my_list:
    if word not in unique_words_list:
    unique_words_list.append(word)
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    for j in range(len(unique_words_list)):
        if my_list[i]==unique_words_list[j]:
            number_list.append(j)


unique_words_list, number_list    
>>>(['hi', 'babe', 'key'], [0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2])
```

Then your list comprehension:

```
[i for i, e in enumerate(number_list) if e == 1]
>>>[1,3]
```

Which means you have a 'babe' on the 1st and 3rd position in your list.

Might be a simpler way! Hope this helps.